# Logic Pro X weird move marquee to transient problem

Tags: mac, keyboard, logic

I have a project where I'm doing a fair amount of editing to get all the various tracks to line up. It's a bunch of recordings of the same songs in the same order, just the gaps are different.

My method is to click the marquee into a click track just ahead of the first click, then use the right arrow key to move it to the first click precisely. Then I can split / trim / move etc.

That works fine on  all the tracks *except* one of the click tracks where the arrow key just seems to move the marquee ahead exactly 500 bars ... and then another 500 bars. I can go back to the other tracks and it behaves as expected.

Why is it doing this on this one region? I just bounced in place and the new audio behaves fine. If I drag the original region to another track it still misbehaves, so I think it's region-dependent.

I have no transients marked, I'm not in transient editing mode. Flex mode is off. This happens in the main window and the audio editor.

Comment: Could you please add some basic formatting(line break, paragraphs) to your question? It currently looks like a wall of text. https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/26896/how-do-i-fix-a-text-wall-when-i-already-have-one

Comment: Thx for the edit.